# Как автоматически проставить ответ при обновлении пакета на старую версию через zypper?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, opensuse

Появилась необходимость откатить пакеты приложения на старую версию скриптом. 
При вводе команды "zypper in --oldpackage имя_пакета" выдается следующее:

Решение 1: будут обновлены след пакеты

Решение 2: не устанавливать

Решение 3: повредить зависимости

Выберите по номеру одно из вышеуказанных решений или отмените [1/2/3/c] (c):

Подскажите как ввести ответ скриптом? 
Ключ -y под данную ситуацию не подходит.